# What would be the right ratio of GC young generation when an application uses big Cache?

Tags: java, caching, garbage-collection, heap-memory

I have a Java web app which uses 10GB cache out of 20GB Heap, the traffic creats new objects which are put into the cache and evicts the old ones;

[image: the graph of the gc log]

If the cache is filled in 1 minutes with new objects, what should be the ratio of the young generation so that the full GC would occur as less as possible?

Comment: is there any problem that makes you think you need to manually size the generations?

Comment: From the graph of the gc log it shows that there are lots of full gc, so I wonder if the new generation set as 2GB is right for this kind of application( keep create new objects and put then into cache).

Answer (score 1):

The question cannot be answered on a theoretical level, with the amount of data you provided. What is the replacement pattern of your application? Is it continuously replacing all the cached content within one minute?

If you extend the young generation size, you might end up with more memory consumption and less frequent full GCs. However, less frequent full GCs will not mean less GC work if all your data is in the young generation.

The best thing is to simply try it. However, when you try different settings make sure that you monitor the relevant over all data of the Java process, CPU times and memory consumption.